# span float left of a img

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how can i float a span tag left of a img tag?i'm trying to clone a dock navigation , but getting stuck and no idea how to solve , can someone point me out?

here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.sidebar-menu').hover(function(){
        $(this).find('span').slideToggle("fast");
    }, function(){
        $(this).find('span').slideToggle("fast");
    });

});
```

here is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/mzvyt/6/

trying to clone this sidebar
http://blog.webguruportfolio.com/2011/03/jquery-plugin-for-youtube-video-slider.html

im stuck at the part how do i slide the content sidebar-title left of the sidebar-icon

[image: weird bug?]

after few times of mouse over / sliding , it will got some weird line appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the javascript to this:

```
$('.sidebar-menu').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('span').animate({right:"20px"},"fast");
}, function(){
    $(this).find('span').animate({right:"-500px"},"fast");
});
```

css

```
#sidebar .sidebar-item .sidebar-menu .sidebar-icon {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:9999;
    background:#333;
}
#sidebar .sidebar-item .sidebar-menu .sidebar-title {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:-500px;
    background:#333;
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    z-index:-9;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mzvyt/6/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mzvyt/3/

erm...weird effect,how to slide from the icon right to left?

Comment: thanks , working nicely , but still got 1 bug @@ check back on my question , i uploaded a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Change you css file to

```
 #sidebar {
color: #fff;
background-color: #333;
width: 50px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-ms-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-o-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-moz-border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
-ms-border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
-o-border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
-webkit-border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
-moz-transition: right 0.15s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: right 0.15s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: right 0.15s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: right 0.15s ease-in-out;
transition: right 0.15s ease-in-out;
position: fixed;
left: -40px;
top: 124px;
z-index: 3000;}

#sidebar:hover {
left: 0px;}
```

Comment: sorry for my bad english , get u misunderstand , im stuck at the part how to slide the content out ,  not changing the right: -40px to left: -40px

http://jsfiddle.net/mzvyt/2/
http://blog.webguruportfolio.com/2011/03/jquery-plugin-for-youtube-video-slider.html

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your just need to use `float` and remove a few things.

Update your CSS for the icon and title as follows. I've floated both to the right (this makes them appear side-by-side). I set the title span to `display:block;` and gave it a fixed height (same height as the icon). Then added a background color.

```
#sidebar .sidebar-item .sidebar-menu .sidebar-icon {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    float:right;
}
#sidebar .sidebar-item .sidebar-menu .sidebar-title {
    background-color: #333;
    float:right;
    height:50px;
    display:block;
}
```

I removed the background color from `#sidebar` and `.sidebar-menu`.

I also updated your jQuery. I recommend using `animate` because it gives you more control over the animation effect. Also, you want to hide them all at first and only show them on `hover`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sidebar .sidebar-title").hide();
    $('.sidebar-menu').hover(function(){
        $(this).find('span').animate({width:"show"},"fast");
    }, function(){
        $(this).find('span').animate({width:"hide"},"fast");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/mzvyt/4/

I added `.stop(true,true)` to the animation line of jQuery to stop the animations from queuing if you hit a bunch at once.

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/mzvyt/5/